# Complexities of the following -insertion sort, selection sort ,merge sort , radix sort and explain which one is best sorting algorithm and why?

Tags: array-algorithms

Complexities of the following -insertion sort, selection sort ,merge sort , radix sort and explain which one is best sorting algorithm and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in the 'best' sorting algorithm. It depends on what you want to do. For instance, bubble sort is really easy to implement and would be the best if you just want a quick and dirty way of sorting a short array. On the other hand, for larger arrays, the time complexity will really come into play and you will notice considerable runtime difference. If you really value memory, then you probably want to evaluate space complexities of these.

So the sort answer is: IMHO, there's no best sorting algorithm. I'll leave the following table for you to evaluate for yourself what you want to use.

<kbd>Sorting Algorithm</kbd><kbd>Avg Time Complextity</kbd><kbd>Space Complexity</kbd>
<kbd>Quicksort</kbd>      <kbd>O(nlog(n))</kbd>      <kbd>O(log(n))</kbd>      
<kbd>Mergesort</kbd>      <kbd>O(nlog(n))</kbd>      <kbd>O(n)</kbd>      
<kbd>Insertionsort</kbd>      <kbd>O(n^2)</kbd>      <kbd>O(1)</kbd>      
<kbd>Selectionsort</kbd>      <kbd>O(n^2)</kbd>      <kbd>O(1)</kbd>      
<kbd>Radixsort</kbd>      <kbd>O(nk)</kbd>      <kbd>O(n+k)</kbd>